# Download API 21 for Android Studio 2

Tags: android, sdk

I wanted to download API 21 and lower, but in SDK manager it doesn't show me. just shows API 23 and it's already installed. how can I add it ??

Answer (score 0):

When you open the Sdk manager theres a check box to show new/available  and another for only installed sdks. Check which one is ticked and toggle

Comment: yes, but ritgh now is shows me just Android6 which it already installed, i want to install lower APIs .but it doesn't show me anything

Answer (score 0):

You will see an option for launching stand alone sdk manager as shown below. There you can find all the "Not installed" components
[image]